# why bootstrap css not applying in real device?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a site and used bootstarp 3.Everything in site is perfect and FF, Chrome,IE, Safari, iphone,ipad all are working fine.

Then I host the site and when I see the site in ipad site is weird.Seems all media queries I have written not applying.But when I check FF > web developer > responsive design view all showing perfectly.Then I analyzed it bit and saw that ipad only reading bootstarp.min.css file.When I change something there ipad showing the changes well.

This makes me crazy and I need to know the reason for this and how to prevent ipad read css and force it to read my css styles.

Thanks

Comment: And the code is...? And the relevant files of the web site are...?

Comment: You're missing the meta viewport tag     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason. I have changed min-device-width and max-device-width in to
min-width and max-width